# how pull beta data from yahoo.finance?

Tags: python, stock, yahoo-finance, variance, yfinance

beta values are calculated in yahoo.finance and thinking I can save time rather calculating through variance and etc. The beta chart can be seen under stock chart. I am able to extract close price an volume for the ticker using the code below:

```
import yfinance as yf
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
df = yf.download('AAPL, MSFT', 
                      start='2021-08-01', 
                      end=date.today(), 
                      progress=False)
adjusted_close=df['Adj Close'].reset_index()
volume=df['Volume'].reset_index()
```

but how can get beta values the same way we get for prices or volumes? I am looking for pulling historical beta data with start and end date.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in a batch, using `concat` instead of the soon-to-be deprecated `append`

```
# import yfinance
import yfinance as yf

# initialise with a df with the columns
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock','Beta','Marketcap'])

# here, symbol_sgx is the list of symbols (tickers) you would like to retrieve data of

# for instance, to retrieve information for DBS, UOB, and Singtel, use the following:
symbol_sgx = ['D05.SI', 'U11.SI','Z74.SI']
 
for stock in symbol_sgx:
    ticker = yf.Ticker(stock)
    info = ticker.info
    beta = info.get('beta')
    marketcap = info.get('marketCap')
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'Stock':stock,'Beta':[beta],'Marketcap':[marketcap]})
    df = pd.concat([df, df_temp], ignore_index=True)

# this line allows you to check that you retrieved the right information        
df
```

`info.get()`  is a better alternative than `info[]` The latter is little buggy; if one of the tickers is errant (eg outdated, delisted) the script would stop. This is especially annoying if you have a long list of tickers, and you don't know which is the errant ticker. `info.get()` would continue to run if no information is available. For these entries, you just need to post-process a df.dropna() to remove NaNs.

Comment: Please check your Markdown syntax when highlighting code. Try to answer these questions to yourself: What does `symbol_sgx` mean? What does the last line of code `df` add to your answer? Will the user understand what you mean?

Comment: thanks! i added in comments. hope this is better! (also made other changes to the code; explanation also provided)

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Finance has a dictionary of company information that can be retrieved in bulk. This includes beta values, which can be used.

```
import yfinance as yf
ticker = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
stock_info = ticker.info
stock_info['beta']
# 1.201965
```

[image]